# Can Google Analytics track data usage?

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to get statistics on how much bandwidth my android app is consuming with Google Analytics. Is this possible ? Should I manually register the size of each request, send it as an event and sum all that data per user ? Is that even possible ?
Everything I find on the internet is unfortunately about how much data Google Analytics itself uses.

Answer (score 0):

It's so negligible very few realistically care about it.

It's hard to count either since the Firebase SDK employs batching, and now even gtag.js employs it on the web. Batching helps to save very considerably on the transport packet headers since the analytics payloads are usually very compact. Many analytics hits can fit a TCP packet.

You can calculate it though. Use something like Charles or Fiddler to proxy your GA events, get an average size of a typical GA payload (probably under a kilobyte) then multiply by the number of events you're sending.

You can do so programmatically from inside the app if you want, but that would be hard to justify.

Comment: No, that's specifically what I don't want ! I want to know how much data the app uses, not how much GA uses.

Comment: oh, well, GA doesn't track it automatically. You'd have to measure it in your code by checking your app's traffic and then send this data to GA.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to send this information to GA so that it sums for each user.

Comment: just send it as a custom metric, registering it in GA4 beforehand: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10075209?hl=en